# List L is merged to self

Tags: c++

I am currently working on my C++ program working with linked lists, and I have absolutely no idea what is meant by "List L is merged with self". I have previous knowledge with linked lists, and never had to merge one into itself.

Here is my format..

```
// pre: none
  // post: list l is merged to self.
  void LinkedList :: merge(const LinkedList& l){


    Node * lstCpy = NULL;
    Node * head = NULL;

    // copy list1 into lstCpy
    Node * cur = l;
    while (cur != NULL) {

        if (head == NULL) {
            lstCpy = new Node;
            head = lstCpy;
        }
        lstCpy->next = new Node;
        lstCpy = lstCpy->next;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"and I have absolutely no idea what is meant by "List L is merged with self"."_ Honestly I don't have a clue either.

Comment: Thats my post condition.. like what does she expect

Comment: Well, something like merging a list with itself (check if `this == &l`) should result in a NOP, while other `l` should perform a merge actually.

Comment: Yea Im having trouble grasping that

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should read "list `l` is merged with `this`"

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your actual task is, but implementing a `merge()` function with the predefined signature you're given would imply that you check if the list should be merged with itself (and do nothing in this case)

```
void LinkedList:merge(const LinkedList& rhs) {
    if(this != &rhs) /* check that merging doesn't ask for the same instance */ {
        // Put the actual merging code
    }
}
```

---

The condition pattern above, checking `if(this != &rhs)` before doing any (unnecessary) operation on the current instance is widely used e.g. for implementation of the assignment operation

```
LinkedList& LinkedList:operator=(const LinkedList& rhs) {
    if(this != &rhs) {
        // assign individual class member values from rhs
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The very point of checking this condition is, to avoid any unnecessary operations that would leave the current instance in the same state anyways.

Merging a list with itself, won't require any action, because the operation is [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). Thus you'll just skip such unnecessary operation by checking for not operating on the same instance in 1st place.

---

```
// post: list l is merged to self.
```

The post condition doesn't mean anything more that `list 1` is merged to *self*, where *self* means your current class instance (`this`). The rules about not merging the same instance to itself still apply.

Comment: I attempted up above but I believe it makes no sense what so ever

Comment: @ProgrammerCrazy Why do you think it makes no sense in particular? It's common practice to do so for such kind of functions (the standard pattern for assignment operator implementation is similar).